# Modifying state from other threads

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I just wrote a trivial JavaFX program. It shows a circle.

Then I start 2 different threads.

One modifies the X position in a loop. The other modifies the Y position. The circle moves. It seems to work.

So, my question is: should I be surprised? Worried? Is it OK?

I am aware of this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

But... somehow I don't need it?

Any input appreciated.﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that modifying UI state from threads other than the FX Application Thread is **not guaranteed** to work. This doesn't mean that it will never work, but it does mean that you should not do it. It may work on a given platform and with a particular implementation of the Java and JavaFX runtimes, but may fail on other platforms, or when you upgrade your JVM, or even just *sometimes* when you run and you happen to get bad timing on when your method calls are executed.

> So, my question is: should I be surprised?

No.

> Worried?

You should worry about the fact that you're not recommended to do this. You should not worry that it appears to work on one or more particular platforms.

> Is it OK?

No.

The fix is easy... keep your threads as they are, do all the computations in those threads, and also any `Thread.sleep(...)` or other pauses you may have, but wrap the calls to `setCenterX(...)` and `setCenterY(...)` in a `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: One other thing: look into the [Animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm), which may well be a more natural way to implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks! Both @Eeliya for asking and @James_D for answering. As the original poster of the question, let me say that I'm very satisfied with this answer (I would mark it as *the* answer if I could). Independent findings on my own also lead me to this conclusion (using `runLater` is the key).